# Angular 6 Forms TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of null

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-forms

I have a simple form with two FormControls, where I subscribe to all valueChanges. But when checking for errors I get this error: [image]
Note that I am first able to log the input, but afterward its `null`.

**Typescript**

```
export class Component {

    @Input() product: Product;

    form: FormGroup;
    errors: any;
    messages: any;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.setupMessages();
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            name: ['', [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(3),
                Validators.maxLength(100),
            ]],
            description: ['', [
                Validators.maxLength(10000),
            ]],
        });
        this.form.patchValue(this.product);
        this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.checkErrors());
    }

    private checkErrors(): void {
        for (let field in this.errors) {
            this.errors[field] = '';
            let input = this.form.get(field);
            // I am able to log input
            // but input.valid is null
            if (!input.valid) {
                for (let error in input.errors) {
                    this.errors[field] = this.messages[field][error];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private setupMessages(): void {
        this.messages = {
            name: {
                required: 'Please give your product an awesome name',
                minlength: 'The name should be longer than 3 characters',
                maxlength: 'Keep your product name under 100 characters',
            },
            description: {
                maxlength: 'Your description is to long',
            },
        }
        this.errors = {
            name: '',
            descripton: '',
        }
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <dy-input
            [required]="true"
            [placeholder]="'Give your product an awesome name'"
            formControlName="name"
            [error]="errors.name"
            [maxlength]="100"
        >
            Name
        </dy-input>
        <dy-textarea
            [placeholder]="'Pointing out details helps to improve sales'"
            [error]="errors.description"
            formControlName="description"
            [height]="'480px'"
            [maxlength]="10000"
        >
            Description
        </dy-textarea>
    </form>
```

As you can see, I am using my own custom Form Controls. But I'm quite sure, that the issue is not caused by them, because of the fact, that they don't cause any errors in other forms.

Comment: input['valid'] modify your code and try

Comment: what is ```dy-input``` or ```dy-textarea```?

Comment: Simplest fix would be to just add an extra condition in your `checkErrors()` function. i.e `if (input && !input.valid)`, but, that doesn't explain *why* it's happening. For that, i'll have to have a think. Could be the double change detection in dev mode, but even then, it should still be ok... 

Comment: @fatemefazli `dy-input` and `dy-textarea` are simply two custom form controls (I could attach them if needed)

Comment: @Nunicorn Yeah that solves the issue, but as you say, it is a realy weird behavior

Comment: @SkateStyle see my answer below... 

Comment: Thanks for the quick support guys, have a great time!

Comment: @SkateStyle you don't need to patch form after building form itself, since in the onInit method you already have your input object, so you can simply combine building and patching: `this.fb.group({name: [this.product.name, [Validators...` .
If your @Input might change in the parent component, you can add logic of form patching inside the onChanges hook.

Comment: @sherlock.92 You are totally right! Thanks men :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second time around, your input **is** null, because of a typo in your errors.

```
private setupMessages(): void {
    this.messages = {
        name: {
            required: 'Please give your product an awesome name',
            minlength: 'The name should be longer than 3 characters',
            maxlength: 'Keep your product name under 100 characters',
        },
        description: {
            maxlength: 'Your description is to long',
        },
    }
    this.errors = {
        name: '',
        descripton: '',
    }
}
```

Note, in `this.errors`, you have an error key called **descripton**, but your formgroup key is **description** (spelled correctly).

You're missing an **i** in the `this.errors` version.

Also, in addition to my comment above, maybe worth editing your condition to be `if (input && !input.valid)` to keep it safe :)